# What does list[i][i] mean?

Tags: python, list

I don't understand what `produkt *= y[i][i]` mean. I have never seen two `[] []` after each other.
Please help

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
y = [x, x, x]
x[1] += 1
y[2] = [4, 4, 4]
x[2] = 0
produkt = 1
for i in range(len(y)):
    produkt *= y[i][i]
print(produkt)
```

Comment: It means nothing different than usual. You have a list of lists, you get an element, and then you get an element of that list. Do `print(y)` to see the shape of `y` if it helps

Comment: Hint: What is `y[i]`? What is `y[i][i]`? Try adding some `print`s to your loop to show them.

Comment: @wjandrea thank you, but I have tried to find out what y'[i][i]' means, but I don't understand it. I have never seen two boxes in a row before

Comment: @Synnøve What have you tried exactly? Do you understand what `y[i]` is? If so, think of it as `w = y[i]`. Then what's `w[i]`?

Comment: y is a square 2 dimensional list. Iterating through y[i][i] means iterating through the diagonal of that 2d list.

Answer (score 0):

This is list of a list or basically a two dimensional list.

Comment: That's `y`. But what's `y[i][i]`?

Comment: Two dimensional array can be considered like a table with rows and columns. y[i][i] is the element of array y in the row i and column i.